# How to do a post in .net core 2 web api with foreign keys

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I have the current models:

```
public class Balance
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public string Storage { get; set; }
    public Coin Coin { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
}

public class Coin
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
}
```

And the following method to post:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> PostNew([FromBody] Balance balance)
    {
        var current_user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(this.User.Identity.Name);
        balance.User = current_user;
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid && balance.Title.Trim() != "")
            {
                if(balance.Amount <= 0)
                {
                    balance.Amount = 0;
                }
                _context.Balance.Add(balance);
                _context.SaveChanges();
                return Ok(Json("Registered new balance!"));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception /*e*/)
        {
            return BadRequest(Json("An error ocurred"));
        }
        return BadRequest(Json("An error ocurred"));
    }
```

I tried multiple JSON formats to post the information:

```
{
"title":"test",
"amount":"50",
"coinid":9
}

{
"title":"test",
"amount":"50",
"coin":9
}

{
"title":"test",
"amount":"50",
"coin": { "id":9 }
}
```

But I always get either a null object exception or an insert with the foreignkey id set to null, I tried looking around but can't find anything on it, I'm relatively new to .net and looking for help, thank you!

**EDIT:**

DB Structure:

[image: database structure]

Comment: try adding with coin code `{
"title":"test",
"amount":"50","storage":xyz"
"coin":{"id":9,"code":"abc"}
}`

Comment: @Prashanth I tried, but what "coin" : {...} does is try to add a new coin into the db, so all it does is give me a "primary key constraint error" I'm trying to add a relation to an already existing coin

Comment: can you share schema of those table coin,balance and user

Comment: added on the edit, user is more complex since it's the asp user, but that one has no issue since it's added when I try `{"title":"test", "amount":"50"}` I get it from the user_manager context and everything is fine, the issue is I have no idea how to send the coin id over

Comment: try with this `{
"title":"test",
"amount":"50",
"coinid":9
}` provided coin id is present in DB as it may be foreign key

Comment: that one does the same as if I did `{"title":"test", "amount":"50"}` coinid is just ignored and coinid in the db is null

Comment: Try to add CoinId property to your Balance model. And set it, instead of setting the Coin.

Comment: I just tried that and had the same result

Answer (score 2):

Finally figured it out, my models NEED to specify a foreign key type like so:

```
public class Balance
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public int CoinId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CoinId")]
    public Coin Coin { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

And now I can use:

{
"title":"test",
"amount":"50",
"coinid":9
}

For anyone else wondering